# Changing color in a measure in SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a Measure, created in SSAS for one of the tables -

```
      Total Hours:=SUM(Timesheets[Hours])
```

Is there a way to make this measure Red color or in Larger font?

So it would be different from the other existing Measures

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't the type of metadata that can be set within SSAS Tabular. What client tools are you using? This can be handled in the rendering of a report.

Comment: @greggyb We'll be using Power BI  where they have all the tools and features; I was just wanted to help someone to see that measure better in SSAS;   But all makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to decorate measures and other model metadata within a Tabular or Power BI model, so that they appear in a special way within client tool. Your best options are:

- **Naming:** Most client tools order the measures alphabetically, so if you have an important measure you want to show at the top of the list, make sure that it starts with some letter, punctuation or number, so that it will be sorted at the top of list.
- **Display Folders:** You could consider moving all measures, except the "important" ones, into a Display Folder.